# Accessing global static variable

Tags: c++

I need to access a global variable from a function. My declaration looks like this:

```
file: HeaderFile.hpp
namespace SomeNamespace {               
    static SomeClass *globalvariable;
}
```

I have to access this from another file(`CPPFILE.cpp` `- in which I have #include HeaderFile.hpp`). I have a local variable:

```
SomeClass *localvariable
```

After modifying this localvariable in a function, I need to assign it to the globalvariable. Like this:

```
SomeNamespace::globalvariable = localvariable;
```

Although it doesn't work. Whatever I type, I get an error. Either that type is not defined (VS reports that it's changing it automatically to int, but then it's class mismatch), or if I write the class before the globalvariable I get an error that I'm trying to redefine it.

Please note that I'm fairly unfamiliar with C++ and pointers.

**EDIT:**

```
SomeNamespace::globalvariable = localvariable
ERROR: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

SomeClass * SomeNamespace::globalvariable = localvariable
ERROR: SomeClass * SomeNamespace::globalvariable redefinition
```

Comment: Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us, and please include the actual errors you get.

Comment: "global static" is a contradiction in terms. I'd suggest revisiting the basics before trying to work on multi-file projects.

Comment: It's also important what the file extensions are and how is the file included.

Comment: Since we still don't have a full example and must continue playing whack-a-mole one at a time: Where is `SomeClass` defined?

Comment: Are you trying to write `SomeNamespace::globalvariable = localvariable` outside of a function? If so, move it into a function.

Comment: Who knows what's going on? All we have are disjointed excerpts with almost no context.

Comment: I'm sorry about this. I have this 20-file "core project" and I'm trying to add different functionalities by adding 5-6 files - still trying to keep this question just about the single problem. And to answer your question - SomeClass is defined in a whole different header file as a struct.

Comment: The error itself looks like you didn't declare `SomeClass` before declaring a pointer to it. Then there's also definition to supply.

Answer (score 3):

If it is static, you cannot access it outside that file. What you probably need is a regular variable and an extern declaration. Observe:

File A:

```
namespace SomeNamespace {               
    SomeClass *globalvariable;
}
```

File B:

```
namespace SomeNamespace {               
    extern SomeClass *globalvariable;
}

//...

SomeClass *localvariable;

//...

SomeNamespace::globalvariable = localvariable;
```

And if you are new to C++ try not to use pointers. Search for smart pointers and/or how to live with stack allocation for these tasks.

Comment: I find your advice about pointers quite curious - smart pointers are pointers, with added ownership & lifetime semantics. They don't replace raw pointers, and we surely don't know enough about OP's case to know whether they'd fit here.

Comment: You are surely correct, but if he is new and without a proper guidance, he might fall into C+ [sic] trap thinking only way to store heap objects is pointers. Even if he does not use them, it would be good for him to know these.

Comment: "Try not to use pointers" does sound like a blanket statement, but I see what you mean.

Comment: If that new, they may not realise they might be able to stack-allocate these things without any requirement for pointers. If we're going to jump to conclusions, smart pointers aren't the only place we can arrive.

Comment: after following this I still get "missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int"

Comment: Yet again: Post a minimal, full example that produces that error, which other users can review and test. Tell us which line it occurs on. Otherwise, do you just want people to guess? There are so many possible causes that it's just not worthwhile.

Comment: It would be best to have a header file contain `extern SomeClass *globalvariable;` and then have the relevant .cpp files include that header. This avoids undiagnosed errors occuring if there is a mismatch in the declarations.

Comment: @Wanderer that is basically saying no such variable. Are you sure that you have included the extern declaration properly?